# Detecting circles of a color gives "image must be 8-bit single-channel in HoughCircle" error in OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap

I am building an Android Application and I want to be able to detect black circles. I am using OpenCV3 for Android and I am able to filter out the black colours from my camera feed using the code below. Kindly note that I used the Color-blob-detection example given in the Android SDK and tweaked the code as such:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    if (mIsColorSelected) {

        Bitmap resultBitmap;

        resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, resultBitmap);

        //TODO - look for circles
        Mat mat = new Mat(resultBitmap.getWidth(), resultBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(resultBitmap, mat);

        final Bitmap bitmap;

        //TODO - filter out the black only
        Mat mHSV = mat;
        Mat mHSVThreshed = mat;
        Mat mRgba2 = mat;

        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV, 0);
        Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), new Scalar(130, 130, 130), mHSVThreshed);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mHSVThreshed, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR, 0);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 0);

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mRgba2, mRgba2, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

        //this is for displaying purposes only. 
        //At this point, the image would be black and white, where the white spots are the black detected blobs 
        //            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba2.cols(), mRgba2.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba2, bmp);
       //bitmap = bmp; //resultBitmap;

        //TODO - new circle detection code: this uses the colour filtered Mat
        mat = mRgba2;
        Imgproc.HoughCircles(mat, circles,
                Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, 100,
                20, 0, 0);

        /* get the number of circles detected */
        int numberOfCircles = (circles.rows() == 0) ? 0 : circles.cols();

        /* draw the circles found on the image */
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++) {

        /* get the circle details, circleCoordinates[0, 1, 2] = (x,y,r)
         * (x,y) are the coordinates of the circle's center
         */

            double[] circleCoordinates = circles.get(0, i);

            int x = (int) circleCoordinates[0], y = (int) circleCoordinates[1];

            Point center = new Point(x, y);
            int radius = (int) circleCoordinates[2];

            /* circle's outline */
            Imgproc.circle(mRgba2, center, radius, new Scalar(0,
                    200, 255), 4);

            /* circle's center outline */
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba2, new Point(x - 5, y - 5),
                    new Point(x + 5, y + 5),
                    new Scalar(0, 200, 255), -1);
        }
        Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba2, resultBitmap);

        bitmap = resultBitmap;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
                mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.GONE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
    }
    return mRgba;
}
```

What my code does is that it takes a snapshot of the camera feed as a Mat, and then using that Mat, I do some image processing on it and to black out everything except the black colour. The resulting Mat is the `mRgba2` variable and I converted to `Bitmap` and displayed on an `ImageView`. I displayed this Bitmap to confirm that I am getting the result I want.

After I know that I'm able to filter out the colour I wanted, I then run a `GaussianBlur` on it then proceed to run `HoughCircles`. However, when I run the

```
Imgproc.HoughCircles(mat, circles,
        Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, 100,
        20, 0, 0);
```

line, I get an

```
The source image must be 8-bit, single-channel in function CvSeq* cvHoughCircles(CvArr*, void*, int, double, double, double, double, int, int)
```

Error.

I know that the code wherein I run HoughCircles on a given mat variable works, because I tested it before. Now, changing the mat variable I feed onto it does not, and I wonder what I did differently for the code to not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HoughCircles runs only on grayscale (CV8U) images.

Replacing

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA, 0);
```

with

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mRgba2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);
```

should remove the error.

Then the problem is to detect circles of a given color. This won't pose much of a problem in your case, because you are detecting black circles anyway. Instead of black circles, this will detect dark circles.

If you have dark colors other than black in some of the circles, you can filter them out separately by looking at the pixel values in a different color space.

Comment: I'll look into this. However, we decided to look for red circles instead.

Comment: You could just use the red channel of the color image in this case as the input to the HoughCircles.